# .net 6 what is the proper way to add a form to a _Layout and handle the post

Tags: razor-pages, .net-6.0

I need to add a subscribe form to my Layout so it is on all pages in the right side area.

How do I handle the post action as layouts dont have a codefile?

What I have so far is my layout has a signup partial and in that partial is the form. At this point I ponder what to do and what is the correct and safe way on handling user input and the action handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Razor page e.g. *Subscribe.cshtml* that handles the form submission and specify that page in the `asp-page` attribute of the form tag helper:

```
<form method="post" asp-page="/Subscribe">
```

Process the submission in the `OnPost` handler of `SubscribeModel`.